# Brace initialization for class with virtual function

Tags: c++, c++11

There is this code:

```
struct A {
   int x;
   void f() {}
};

struct B {
   int y;
   virtual void f() {}
};

A a = {2};

//B b = {3}; error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'B'

int main() {
   return 0;
}
```

Why initialization for variable `a` works but not for variable `b`?

Comment: Brace initialization only works for POD types; making your method virtual makes it non-POD

Comment: [What are Aggregates and Pods and how/why they are special](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`A` is an aggregate, and so can have brace initialization, and `B` isn't, since it has a virtual method.

**8.5.1 Aggregates**

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no brace-or-equal-
>   initializers for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11),
>   no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

Comment: The answer is right, but there is no need to qualify with the '11 standard, as the answer is exactly the same in C++98, C++03 and C++11

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Thanks again. I wasn't sure if this was phrased in terms of aggregate or POD in C++03.

Comment: couldn't you write a brace initializer constructor however? taking an initializer list as an arg?

Comment: @DavidRodriguez Wouldn't uniform initialization in C++11 that uses braces be called "brace-initialization"?

Comment: @Need4Sleep yes you could, in C++11.

Comment: @Need4Sleep also, adding a constructor taking a single `int` would allow for the same initialization syntax.